# int to String to concat?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    int num = 5;
    char hi[15] = "15";
    strcat(hi, num)

}
```

Any way to do this easily? For example, I want to make the num into a string and concatenate it so it becomes 155.

Comment: Use sprintf (or better snprintf) ?

Comment: Note the types in the prototype for `strcat` (`char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);` -- both are *character* types -- not `int`. You could add `char digit[2] = { num + '0', 0 };` and then do `strcat (hi, digit);` (only for `num` equal `[0-9]`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

int findDigits(int n){

    int count = 0;

    //if it's a single digit
    if( (n/10) == 0){

        return 1;
    }

    while(n /= 10){

        count++;
    }

    return count;
} 

int main() {

    int num = 5;
    char hi[15] = "15";
    char* buf = NULL;

    int digits = findDigits(num);

    if(digits > 0){

        if( (buf = malloc(digits + 1)) == NULL){

            return -1;
        }

        if( (strlen(hi) + digits) >= sizeof(hi) ){

            free(buf);
            return -1;
        }

        sprintf(buf, "%d", num);
        strcat(hi ,buf);

        free(buf);
        printf("%s", hi);

        getchar(); 
    }
    else{

        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int num = 5;
    char buff1[15] = "15";
    char buff2[25];

    sprintf(buff2, "%s%d", buff1, num);
```

Be sure to check the return value of sprintf().  And of course make sure buff2 is big enough for both buff1 and the string version of num.

Comment: I think it's UB to use the same string for input and output here.

Comment: Updated my answer to use two buffers

Comment: Agree, I wouldn't code it exactly that way, but it addresses the functional question the OP asked without introducing more complex code he may or may not be ready to understand.

Comment: @Michael Walz char buff2[25]; when int is 4 bytes so it can contain all 10 digits.Which means even if num is say 3 digits you still use memory for 10 digits